# Hibernate not working in Linux Mint 14 KDE after nvidia driver update

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, power-management, hibernate

I've had some problems with the X server ramping up CPU usage, so I wanted to check if it goes away to a new Nvidia driver. I was at 304.xx and jumped to 319.49.

Now, every time I try to hibernate, I just get thrown back to the login screen (identical to a X restart). After examining `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` from today and the days before i've noticed that the the **before** logs ended with something like:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend hibernate hibernate:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend hibernate hibernate: success.
Mon Aug 26 23:56:43 CEST 2013: performing hibernate
```

And the new ones end with just the first line of that:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate:
```

Things to keep in mind:

- Before I could get things going I had to cleanup on old versions of the driver because it complained of incopatibilities between these driver and kernel modules. I did a `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*' and then blacklisted nouveau in grub.
- I tried `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade` and there is nothing new.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```
# you might not want to purge, but I had little to keep and wanted to be sure
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-325
```

I've just about given up on a manual fix, when somewhere in the package lists something caught my eye. It was a package named `nvidia-319`. You would suppose that this is the nvidia 319.xx series of drivers, and you would be right:).

So I've installed the newest package which was `nvidia-325`, and now I have the newest drivers and working stock hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately suspend has many problem , When you un suspend in you linux-box, many library unloaded and you can't load or some of device will be turn off such as wifi.

i use `pm-hibernate`.

Of course. your kernel must support them.